# Can a Frege module span over multiple files?

Tags: frege

Some languages allow modules to span over multiple files. In Frege this would mean that the namespace of a module would be "open" to later extensions.
I assume this is not possible since modules are located by their compiled class file - unless there would be some clever naming tricks going on.
I just wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it can't. One module, one file.